# Java Poll or Listen to URL for response [Java SE]

Tags: java, http, polling

I have a module which requests status(technically a JSON object) from an FHEM server(home automation) using a simple HTTP post.

How can i poll the requestState method so as to continuously listen (like every 125ms) on the URL for changes in status?

[note: i am not using any server, this is a plain Java program called from a Main function.]

To give an illustration:

```
public static boolean requestState(){
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8083/fhem?cmd=jsonlist+device1");
try{
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader( 
                   new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
                    //response is a JSONObject
        JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result.toString());

                    //get the status from the JSON object
        System.out.println(o.getJSONObject("Result").get("STATE"));
        String STATE = o.getJSONObject("Result").get("STATE");
                    if(STATE.equals("OPEN"))
                       return false;
                    else
                       return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What i would like to achieve is:

```
keep listening to URL
  parse response to judge the status
  if status == OPEN
    soundAlarm();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep both posting a request and reading the result in a loop and use Thread.sleep to put pauses if needed between each poll and the other. I'm not familiar with FHEM but maybe there is a more efficient way that you could use where FHEM pushes the status change to your app rather than having to poll it continually.

Comment: hey Thanks, but i checked a lot on FHEM, sadly a response via POST is the only way (as of now) to fetch the status.

Comment: Then I guess calling requestState in an infinite loop is the only option that comes to my mind. you may need to insert pauses between polls (using Thread.sleep) if FHEM server can't handle the amount of requests your generating